# Weird bug in median of medians as pivot to find Kth max element

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, quickselect, median-of-medians

**Finally I found the bug, please look at the second EDIT**

But there is still that question, you see, the last fourth row of "getMedian()" method, I sort the medians[] array to find the median of medians. Personally I think this breaks the worst case time complexity = O(n), is it correct?

---

I try to use median of medians as the pivot to partition the array to find the Kth max element.

But the bug is so weird: For example {8, 5, 2, 0, 9, 1}, the output is :

- k = 1, output >> 9.
- k = 2, output >> 9.
- k = 3, output >> 5.
- k = 4, output >> 2.
- k = 5, output >> 1.
- k = 6, output >> 0.
- The second max element's output is wrong, others well.

```
public class FindKthMax_MOM {
// Find Kth max by median of medians pivot method.
// Time complexity, worst case = O(n).
// n is the num of the elem in the given array.
private static LNode <Integer> mergeSortLLForIntDataFromMinToMax (LNode <Integer> head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) return head;
    // Get the mid point of this linked list.
    LNode <Integer> preSlower = head;
    LNode <Integer> slower = head;
    LNode <Integer> faster = head;
    while (faster != null && faster.next != null) {
        preSlower = slower;
        slower = slower.next;
        faster = faster.next.next;
    }
    // Cut off this main linked list.
    preSlower.next = null;

    // Do recursion on the left part and the right part.
    LNode <Integer> left = mergeSortLLForIntDataFromMinToMax(head);
    LNode <Integer> right = mergeSortLLForIntDataFromMinToMax(slower);

    // Merge left part and the right part from min to max.
    LNode <Integer> currHead = new LNode <Integer> ();
    LNode <Integer> tempCurrHead = currHead;
    while (left != null && right != null) {
        if (left.data <= right.data) {
            // Add the elem of left part into the linked list.
            tempCurrHead.next = left;
            left = left.next;
        } else {
            // Add the elem of right part into the linked list.
            tempCurrHead.next = right;
            right = right.next;
        }
        tempCurrHead = tempCurrHead.next;
    }
    if (left != null) {
        // Add the remaining part of left part into the main linked list.
        tempCurrHead.next = left;
        left = left.next;
        tempCurrHead = tempCurrHead.next;
    } else if (right != null) {
        // Add the remaining part of right part into the main linked list.
        tempCurrHead.next = right;
        right = right.next;
        tempCurrHead = tempCurrHead.next;
    }
    return currHead.next;
}

private static int partition_second (int[] givenArray, int start, int end, int pivotIndex) {
    int pivot = givenArray[pivotIndex];
    int left = start;
    int right = end;
    while (left <= right) {
        while (givenArray[left] < pivot) left ++;
        while (givenArray[right] > pivot) right --;
        if (left <= right) {
            // Exchange the givenArray[left] and the givenArray[right].
            exchange(givenArray, left, right);
            left ++;
            right --;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
private static void quickSortFromMinToMax (int[] givenArray, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) return;
    // Generate a random num in the range[start, end].
    int rand = start + (int)(Math.random() * ((end - start) + 1));
    // Use this random num as the pivot index to partition the given array in the current scope.
    int split = partition_second (givenArray, start, end, rand);
    // Do recursion.
    quickSortFromMinToMax(givenArray, start, split - 1);
    quickSortFromMinToMax(givenArray, split, end);
}
private static int getMedianFromLL (LNode <Integer> head) {
    if (head == null) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    // Get the mid point of this linked list.
    LNode <Integer> slower = head;
    LNode <Integer> faster = head;
    while (faster != null && faster.next != null) {
        slower = slower.next;
        faster = faster.next.next;
    }
    return slower.data;
}
private static int getMedian (int[] givenArray, int start, int end) {
    int size = end - start + 1;

    int numOfSubSet = (float)(size) / 5 > (size / 5) ? (size / 5 + 1) : (size / 5);

    if (numOfSubSet <= 1) {
        // Sort this little array, and return its median.
        quickSortFromMinToMax(givenArray, start, end);
        return givenArray[(start + end) / 2];
    }
    // Split this entire given array into subset.
    int givenArrayIndex = start;
    LList <LList<Integer>> mainLL = new LList <LList<Integer>> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSubSet; i ++) {
        // Use the linked list to store each sub set.
        LList <Integer> subLL = new LList <Integer> ();

        // Load this subLL by the elems of givenArray.
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j ++) {
            if (givenArrayIndex <= end) {
                subLL.addNode (givenArray[givenArrayIndex]);
                givenArrayIndex ++;
            } else break;
        }
        // Sort this linked list by merge sort.
        subLL.head = mergeSortLLForIntDataFromMinToMax(subLL.head);         
        mainLL.addNode (subLL);
    }
    // Calculate each median for each subset.
    int[] medians = new int[numOfSubSet];
    int mediansIndex = 0;
    LNode <LList<Integer>> tempSubSet = mainLL.head;
    while (tempSubSet != null) {
        medians[mediansIndex] = getMedianFromLL (tempSubSet.data.head);
        mediansIndex ++;
        tempSubSet = tempSubSet.next;
    }

    // Sort the medians array.
    quickSortFromMinToMax (medians, 0, numOfSubSet - 1);

    // Return the median of medians.
    return medians[numOfSubSet / 2];

}
private static void exchange (int[] givenArray, int firstIndex, int secondIndex) {
    int tempElem = givenArray[firstIndex];
    givenArray[firstIndex] = givenArray[secondIndex];
    givenArray[secondIndex] = tempElem;
}
private static int partition (int[] givenArray, int start, int end, int pivot) {
    int left = start;
    int right = end;
    while (left <= right) {
        while (givenArray[left] > pivot) left ++;
        while (givenArray[right] < pivot) right --;
        if (left <= right) {
            // Exchange the givenArray[left] and the givenArray[right].
            exchange(givenArray, left, right);
            left ++;
            right --;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
private static int findKthMax_MOM_Helper (int[] givenArray, int start, int end, int k) {
    if (start > end) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    // Get the median of the givenArray in the current scope.
    int median = getMedian (givenArray, start, end);

    // Use this median as the pivot to partition the given array in the current scope.
    int split = partition (givenArray, start, end, median);

    if (k == split) return givenArray[split - 1];
    else if (k < split) return findKthMax_MOM_Helper(givenArray, start, split - 1, k);
    else return findKthMax_MOM_Helper(givenArray, split, end, k);
}
public static int findKthMax_MOM (int[] givenArray, int k) {
    int size = givenArray.length;
    if (k < 1 || k > size) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    return findKthMax_MOM_Helper(givenArray, 0, size - 1, k);
}

// Main method to test.
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // Test data: {8, 5, 2, 0, 9, 1}.
    int[] givenArray = {8, 5, 2, 0, 9, 1};

    // Test finding the Kth max by median of medians as pivot method.
    System.out.println("Test finding Kth max by median of medians as pivot method, rest = " + findKthMax_MOM(givenArray, 2));
}
}
```

Another question:

At the last second row of the `getMedian (int[] givenArray, int start, int end)` method, I sort the medians array, I think this operation breaks the time complexity of O(n), is it correct?

---

EDIT

Personally I think, the bug may exist in two place:

- In the "`partition (int[] givenArray, int start, int end, int pivot)`"
- >

[CODE]

```
private static int partition (int[] givenArray, int start, int end, int pivot) {
    int left = start;
    int right = end;
    while (left <= right) {
        while (givenArray[left] > pivot) left ++;
        while (givenArray[right] < pivot) right --;
        if (left <= right) {
            // Exchange the givenArray[left] and the givenArray[right].
            exchange(givenArray, left, right);
            left ++;
            right --;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
```

- In the "`findKthMax_MOM_Helper (int[] givenArray, int start, int end, int k)`"
- >

[CODE]

```
private static int findKthMax_MOM_Helper (int[] givenArray, int start, int end, int k) {
    if (start > end) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    // Get the median of the givenArray in the current scope.
    int median = getMedian (givenArray, start, end);

    // Use this median as the pivot to partition the given array in the current scope.
    int split = partition (givenArray, start, end, median);

    if (k == split) return givenArray[split - 1];
    else if (k < split) return findKthMax_MOM_Helper(givenArray, start, split - 1, k);
    else return findKthMax_MOM_Helper(givenArray, split, end, k);
}
```

---

Second **EDIT**
Finally I found the bug, the wrong part of my code is at the "getMedian()" method, look at the last three sentences of that method.

 **[CODE]**

```
private static int getMedian (int[] givenArray, int start, int end) {
    int size = end - start + 1;

    int numOfSubSet = (float)(size) / 5 > (size / 5) ? (size / 5 + 1) : (size / 5);

    if (numOfSubSet <= 1) {
        // Sort this little array, and return its median.
        quickSortFromMinToMax(givenArray, start, end);
        return givenArray[(start + end) / 2];
    }
    // Split this entire given array into subset.
    int givenArrayIndex = start;
    LList <LList<Integer>> mainLL = new LList <LList<Integer>> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSubSet; i ++) {
        // Use the linked list to store each sub set.
        LList <Integer> subLL = new LList <Integer> ();

        // Load this subLL by the elems of givenArray.
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j ++) {
            if (givenArrayIndex <= end) {
                subLL.addNode (givenArray[givenArrayIndex]);
                givenArrayIndex ++;
            } else break;
        }
        // Sort this linked list by merge sort.
        subLL.head = mergeSortLLForIntDataFromMinToMax(subLL.head);
        mainLL.addNode (subLL);
    }
    // Calculate each median for each subset.
    int[] medians = new int[numOfSubSet];
    int mediansIndex = 0;
    LNode <LList<Integer>> tempSubSet = mainLL.head;
    while (tempSubSet != null) {
        medians[mediansIndex] = getMedianFromLL (tempSubSet.data.head);
        mediansIndex ++;
        tempSubSet = tempSubSet.next;
    }

    // Sort the medians array.
    quickSortFromMinToMax (medians, 0, numOfSubSet - 1);

    // Return the median of medians.
    int median = medians[0];
    if (numOfSubSet > 2) median = numOfSubSet % 2 == 0 ? medians[numOfSubSet / 2 - 1] : medians[numOfSubSet / 2];
    return median;
}
```

Comment: You cannot seriously expect anyone to search through your 180 lines of posted code to find your bug. Start your debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: This is too much code; please try to localize the bit of your code where the error should be.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I think that the error is in your `LList`. I've tried with this quick and dirty implementation of `LList` and your code works fine.

```
public class LList<T> {
    public LNode<T> head;

    public void addNode(T i) {
        LNode<T> lNode = new LNode<>();
        lNode.data = i;
        lNode.next = head;
        head = lNode;
    }

    //only for testing
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        LNode<T> node = head;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (;node!=null;node=node.next){
            sb.append(node.data.toString());
            sb.append(",");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class LNode<T> {
    LNode<T> next;
    T data;
}
```

Giving for

```
System.out.println("Test finding ..., rest = " + findKthMax_MOM(givenArray, 1));
System.out.println("Test finding ..., rest = " + findKthMax_MOM(givenArray, 2));
System.out.println("Test finding ..., rest = " + findKthMax_MOM(givenArray, 3));
System.out.println("Test finding ..., rest = " + findKthMax_MOM(givenArray, 4));
System.out.println("Test finding ..., rest = " + findKthMax_MOM(givenArray, 5));
System.out.println("Test finding ..., rest = " + findKthMax_MOM(givenArray, 6));
```

the expected results:

```
Test finding ..., rest = 9
Test finding ..., rest = 8
Test finding ..., rest = 5
Test finding ..., rest = 2
Test finding ..., rest = 1
Test finding ..., rest = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, fonkap. Finally I found the bug, the wrong part of my code is calculating the median of medians, which is in the "getMedian()" method. And the problem is not in the linked list. But anyway, thank you so much. Thank you for your time and help. I have modified the "getMedian()" method in the second "EDIT", the modified part is at last three sentences of that method.

Comment: But fonkap, may I ask you another question? You see the last four row of the "getMedian()" method, I sort the "medians[]" array to find the median of medians. But personally I think this breaks the worst case time complexity O(n), is it correct?

Comment: Oh man! you're right, I was testing over the modified array :( But I'm afraid your algorithm is still broken, could you test with k==4?? it's giving me 9!

Comment: I'll need some more time to find the new bug and to answer your second question, It has been many years since I don't calculate complexities... sorry a lot.

Comment: Hi fonkap, I have tried k = 4, the answer is 2, it is correct.